# FLEX: flash-component not receiving it's own custom event

Tags: flash, apache-flex, components, swc, dispatchevent

I made a movieclip in flash that dispatches a custom event: MyEvent.THE_TYPE = "the_type"

in flex I have: `<local:my_flash_mc the_type="do_something()"`

however, this is not working.

in flash, my event bubbles is set to true. everything works fine in flash.

in flex I am NOT using:

```
<fx:Metadata>
  [Event(name="the_type", type="...")]  
</fx:Metadata>
```

... because I think that this only pertains to custom flex events; plus the .swc is already compiled, so no reason to identify the event class in the type param here.

I tried creating a 'name' property in my event class, but that didn't do it.

any thoughts?

thanks

Comment: please see: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3668890#3668890

for a detailed explanation of how I solved my problem ... the main issue ( for me ) was [EVENT ...] metadata ... once I put it inside my flash mc, Flex began to recognize the component's need for the custom event ( code hinting listed the event ).

Comment: @user689152 The proper way to answer your own question is to answer your own question and mark it as such.  Even though, your solution (to use metadata) doesn't make much sense to me.  the presence of metadata should have no affect on whether or not events fire and the question you link to focuses on code hinting; whereas your question here claims the event doesn't fire. Two very different issues.

Comment: sorry about that ... but stackoverflow would not allow me to 'answer' my question until at least 8 hours after my original post... WHY does my answer not make sense to you?? I didn't say I was having trouble firing the event ... I said I was having trouble receiving the event ... and without the [Event ... ] metadata in my flash component, the flex plugin for flash cannot dispatch the event to the flex environment ( though the flash environment will function as expected ) ...

Comment: @user689152 True; you did say you were having trouble receiving (AKA Listening to) the event.  However, your answer has nothing to do with that; it only relates to code hinting in MXML.  Both my answer and @J_A_X answer tell you how to listen for an event in ActionScript w/o having to have the metadata in place.

Comment: I mentioned the code-hinting because it is an indicator that flex indeed has, at least, 'access' to the event. Without that 'access' it could never hear it one way or the other ... code-hinting was a benchmark in the problem solving process ( for me ).

Comment: I see that I could also NOT have used the [Event ... ] metadata inside my flash mc AND instead have used my_flash_component.addEventListener( "the_event" , the_handler ) within the <fx:Script><![CDATA[ ... ]]> ... thanks for everyone's patience.

Comment: Since you have your solution; be sure to select an answer formally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see: forums.adobe.com/message/3668890#3668890 for a detailed explanation of how I solved my problem ...

the main issue, for me, was the [Event ...] metadata tag.

once I put it *inside my flash mc*, Flex began to recognize the component's need for the custom event ( code hinting listed the event ).

Comment: -1 to this answer for reasons previously stated in comments to the main question.  Flex does not need metadata to listen to events or to dispatch them.  Metadata is only used for code hinting in the IDE (and ASDoc generation).

Comment: you gave me a -1 for answering the question? what is wrong with you ... my answer works ... if it doesn't work for you, then give a meaningful explanation as to the disparity between your own solution and mine ... but don't start giving negations ... you will mislead people in the future who might come across this post.

Comment: I gave you a -1 for providing an answer with no relation to your actual question.  From my comments on the initial question: "the presence of metadata should have no affect on whether or not events fire and the question you link to focuses on code hinting; whereas your question here claims the event doesn't fire. Two very different issues" Metadata has nothing to do with whether an event fires or not; it only relates to code hinting.

Comment: the process of solutionization is often a evolutionary, meandering path ... to expect every solution to have a direct linearity to its originating problem is unrealistic.

your -1 misleads future readers ... the fact that my solution has  "no relation to (my) actual question" is due to the nature of problem solving itself (and, frankly, is a subjective opinion on your part) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use your MC like that in Flex because of the limitation between Flash and Flex.  You'll have to manually add event listeners to your MC using 'addEventListener'.

Answer (score 0):

Please define what "not working" means.  I assume you are receiving a compiler warning.  This code:

```
<fx:Metadata>
  [Event(name="the_type", type="...")]  
</fx:Metadata>
```

Tells the Flex Compiler that the event exists and will let it be used in code hinting in MXML.  So, I'm guessing that this:

```
<local:my_flash_mc the_type="do_something()" />
```

Is throwing a compiler error.  Is that correct?  The solution is to add the event listener in ActionScript:

```
my_Flash_MC_Instance.addEventListener('the_type',do_something);
```

In the do_something handler method, you will have to pass the event (which isn't required in MXML):

```
protected function do_something(event:MyEvent):void{
 // processing here
}
```

Comment: 'not working': the flash component is receiving it's mousedown event ( defined in the flash mc ... on the timeline in flash ). the mousedown event is dispatching a custom event ( I can trace it from within the mc: onHandleMyCustomEvent ... now I have it commented out so that it does not capture the event ). The code hinting in flex does NOT show anything related to my custom event. The flex compiler is NOT throwing an error ( I wish it was ).

Comment: I am using the approach that I found here: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/under-the-hood-with-adobe/create-custom-flex-components-with-flash-cs3/ ... he does NOT use <fx:Metadata>

Comment: @user689152 There is no need to specify metadata to dispatch or listen to an event.  How do you know the Flash Component is recieving it's mousedown event?  You mention the timeline, but such information would not be available to you when using the component as a SWC in a Flex app.  You mention you can trace inside the handler. If so the event must be firing.

Comment: the flash component had a trace within it's own mouse_down handler ... that trace was showing in the Console in Flex ... the event was always firing, but I could not get flex to detect it

Comment: @user689152 You're going to have to provide more code for us to determine what is wrong.  What you are saying seems implausible.